# Find the remainder when $1111^{2019}$ is divided by $11111$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I honestly have no clue what to do. I thought I'd start by defining $11111$ as $x$ and then re-writing the expression as $\frac{(\frac{x-1}{10})^{2019}}{x}$ but I do not what to do from there.

Comment: Do you know the Chinese Remainder Theorem? If so, I suggest factorising $11111$ first

Comment: actually, your method is very good. Apply some rules of modular arithmetic and you have done

Comment: @MattB this time it is not so easy to apply CRT.

Comment: It might help to know that $1111^{10}\equiv 1\bmod 11111$.

Comment: and $1111\times10=11111-1$, so $1111^{-1}\equiv-10\equiv11111-10=11101 (\bmod 11111)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
1111^{2019} = (11111-10000)^{2019}\equiv -(10000)^{2019} \\= - 10^{4*2019} =
-10^{5*1615}*10 = -100000^{1615}*10 \\= -(1 + 9*11111)^{1615}*10 \equiv -10 \equiv 11101 \pmod{11111}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let me add my little fiddle ...

Considering $1111^2=1111*1000+1111*100+1111*10+1111$
$$
\begin{matrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 &  \\
 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 &  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 &  &  & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 
\end{matrix}
$$
Summing up vertically: $1111^2=123\color{red}4321$

The same way we get $11111*111=11111*100+11111*10+11111 = 123\color{red}3321$

From the red digit: $1111^2=11111*111+1000 \equiv 10^3 \pmod {11111}$

From there, $1111^{2k} \equiv 10^{3k} \pmod {11111}$ ... (1)

Since $2018 = 1009*2$ we choose $k=1009$

We know $100000 = 9(11111)+1$ that says $10^5 \equiv 1 \pmod {11111}$

$10^{5k}\equiv 1^k \pmod {11111}$ ...(2)

For $5k$ closest to $3.2019$ we need $3*9=27$ to be of closer units to $0$ or $5$ which means $2019*3 \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$

From (2) ... $10^{1009*3} \pmod {11111} \equiv 10^{5k}10^2 \pmod {11111} \equiv 10^2 \pmod {11111}$ ... (3)

With $1111*100=111100=111110-10=11111*10-10\equiv -10 \pmod{11111}$ ... (4)

Combining (3) and (4) with (1) ... $1111^{2019} = 1111^{2018}*1111 \equiv 1111*10^2 \pmod[11111] \equiv -10 \pmod {2019}$

ie what to be found.

> Ps: You can also start directly from $1111^k*10^k \equiv -1^k \pmod{11111}$, while i thought inherently that we are constrained to exponentiation by squaring method.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Exodd is already the correct one, here a fun fact (and more involved answer). It is possible to show that 
$$
\{ 1111^{n + 10} \, \% \, 11111 \}_{n=0...9} \, = \, \{ 1, 1111, 1000, 11011, 10, 11110, 10000, 10111, 100, 11101  \}
$$ 
So for $2019$ you have to consider $1111^{9}$, which is the last value in the list above.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $11111=41\cdot271$.

---

Mod $41$
$$
\begin{align}
1111^{2019}
&\equiv4^{19}&\pmod{41}\tag1\\
&\equiv4^9&\pmod{41}\tag2\\
&\equiv31&\pmod{41}\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $1111\equiv4\pmod{41}$ and $2019\equiv19\pmod{40}$
$(2)$: $4^{10}\equiv1\pmod{41}$
$(3)$: [square and multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

---

Mod $271$
$$
\begin{align}
1111^{2019}
&\equiv27^{129}&\pmod{271}\tag4\\
&\equiv27^9&\pmod{271}\tag5\\
&\equiv261&\pmod{271}\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(4)$: $1111\equiv27\pmod{271}$ and $2019\equiv129\pmod{270}$
$(5)$: $27^{10}\equiv1\pmod{271}$
$(6)$: square and multiply

---

Since $31\equiv-10\pmod{41}$ and $261\equiv-10\pmod{271}$, we have $1111^{2019}\equiv-10\pmod{11111}$. So the remainder is $11101$.

Comment: Hey Mr rob, nice to see you doing these kicking answers again, pls tell me do the equations 1 and 4 have anything to do with fermat theorem ?

Comment: Both use $x^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p}$ to reduce the exponent.